# add column to data.frame by another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes in my program, one of which stores the information about purchases (including product IDs), the other stores information about products, (product IDs and brand names(as factor))
I want to add to 1st dataframe column with brand names for each product.
I want something like:

```
purchases$brand <- products[purchases$product_id == products$id,]$brand
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You may benefit by looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 1):

Use `%in%` operator, below command will add new column `Brand` to `purchases` data frame based on the matching `product$id` and `purchases$product_id`

```
 purchases$brand <- products$brand[products$id %in% purchases$product_id]
```